# Error Packet for query is too large

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqlconnector

Estoy tratando de hacer una conexión a mi base de datos pero me dice que el paquete es muy largo pero no se como solucionarlo dejo mi código

Estuve investigando sobre el error que me arroja pero no encuentro una solución de hecho en la consola de salida me dice:

com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (4739923 > 1048576). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.
java.lang.NullPointerException

```
public static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/PRUEBAS";
public static final String USERNAME = "root";
public static final String PASSWORD = "12345";


private void btnConectarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    try {
        Connection con = null;
        con = getConnection();

        PreparedStatement ps;
        ResultSet res;
        ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Type "); 
        res = ps.executeQuery();

        if (res.next()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, res.getString("codType") + " " + res.getString("type"));
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No existen datos");
        }

        con.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public static Connection getConnection() {
    Connection con = null;

    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(URL, URL, PASSWORD); 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexión exitosa");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    return con;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Es por que  supera el valor permitido de tu peticion. lo que tendras que realizar es modificar `max_allowed_packet` de tu base.

Ejemplo accediendo a el archivo(puede variar la ruta):

/etc/mysql/my.cnf

en el archivo buscas

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=1M
```

y modificas el valor al parecer tiene definido 1M

Otra opcion seria desde shell:

> shell> mysqld --max_allowed_packet=5M

[Referencia packet-too-large](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/packet-too-large.html)